# How can I prevent default double-tap behavior (zooming, panning) in Mobile Safari on iOS4?

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, webkit, ios4

When I double-tap near the edge of a page that exceeds the height or width of the browser window in Safari under iOS4, it zooms in or out and/or scrolls up, down, right, or left, depending on the size of the page and the current viewport position.  How can I prevent this behavior, please?

I'm working on a site where this is (very) bad; we're preserving several layers of menu state and scrolling horizontally to navigate between layers.  Double-tapping hoses the layout, and there's no intuitive way to get it back.

Double-tap does not seem to fire a scroll or touch event as far as I can tell.  Other things I've tried:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />`

... with variations:

- user-scalable=no
- user-scalable=0
- width=device-width
- width=320

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like making absolutely certain that none of my important elements--I have a static header, scrolling body, and static footer, and the header and body can both scroll sideways--actually exceed the viewport width and have overflow:hidden seems to have done the trick.

Very sad there's nothing official on this, because it's annoying, and breaks most of the other examples I've found online

Answer (score 2):

You have a small typo in you meta tag, between each setting you should use comma. ex.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
```

Comment: I just made a sample document and tested on my iPhone and it worked as expected. (http://ninjadev.org/stackoverflow/viewport.html) Do you have a link to the page, so I can try it my self?

Answer (score 1):

I find that the `<meta name="viewport" ...>` tag generally works on iOS to prevent scaling with double-tap but on the iPad3 on iOS 5.1 there are occasional rare circumstances, which I have difficulty reproducing, where the double-tap zoom gets activated and subsequently screws up the page layout. The behavior is quite buggy. Perhaps [using Javascript](http://appcropolis.com/blog/implementing-doubletap-on-iphones-and-ipads/) to manage tap events can help to prevent this from happening while we wait for Apple to fix this. It's difficult to test without having a way to reproduce the bug though.

Disclaimer: I have not tested this method.